# Statistics: Moment Generating Function questions

Tags: statistics

Struggling to get my head around this question. Help would be much appreciated.

Which of the following mathematical equations relating to the moment generating function associated with the random variable $X$, denoted by $M_X(t)=E[e^{tX}]$, is true?

(a)

$$\frac{dM_X(t)}{dx}\bigg|_{x=0}=E[X]$$

(b)

$$\frac{d^2 M_X(t)}{dt^2}\bigg|_{t=0}=\text{Var}(X)$$

(c)

$$\frac{d^2 \ln M_X(t)}{dt^2}\bigg|_{t=0}=\text{Var}(X)$$

(d)

$$\text{None of the above}$$

My Solution: I'm assuming its just a definition question. The notes I've got were not very helpful, but from what I understood the solution is "a"?

Thanks guys =)

Comment: in (a) there's differentiation by $x$. Also please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: It should be c.

Comment: And even more differentiation in (b) and (c).  If exactly one choice is correct it must be (d) (based on the nitpicky fact that the mgf might not be differentiable at 0), from which point of view (a),(b), and (c) are equally false).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,
$$M_X(0)=E[1]=1$$
$$M'_X(0)=E[X]$$
$$M''_X(0)=E[X^2]$$

For c, we have
$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\ln M_X(t)\bigg|_{t=0}=\left[\frac{M''_X(t)}{M_X(t)}-\frac{M'_X(t)^2}{M_X(t)^2} \right]_{t=0}$$
$$=\frac{M''_X(0)}{M_X(0)}-\frac{M'_X(0)^2}{M_X(0)^2}$$
$$=E[X^2]-E[X]^2 =\text{Var}(X)$$

Answer (score 0):

For the random variable $X$, the moment generating function is defined as $M_{X}(t) = E[e^{tX}]$. Suppose $M_{X}(t)$ is finite for $|t|\leq t_{0}$ for some $t_{0} > 0$.

Then $M_{X}(t) = E[e^{tX}]$

$$\Rightarrow M_{X}(t) = \mathbb{E}[e^{tX}] = \mathbb{E}(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(tX)^k}{k!}) = \mathbb{E}(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{k}X^{k}}{k!}).$$

Now since $M_{X}(t)$, using a result from measure theory, we can interchange the expectation and the series to get:

$$M_{X}(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{k}\mathbb{E}(X^{k})}{k!}.$$

Again, since the series is finite, we can simply take the derivative of the inside of the sum to achieve

$$M_{X}^{'}(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{k}\mathbb{E}(X^{k+1})}{k!}.$$

Setting $t=0$ we get the result $M_{X}^{'}(0) = \mathbb{E}[X]$.